# Add Dynamic Data to Datatable in angular.js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to know how to Add Dynamic Data to Datatable in angular.js
Actually I am using angular.js for plotting the data and after plotting the data i am applying jquery datatable on it.Now on further Ajax call if i am trying to update the data in the grid it is not updating. If i am doing it without applying dataTable then it is working fine.Please help me in t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out ng-grid from Angular-UI.

first you must disable the dataTable plugin, then update the data, then call dataTable plugin again.

Also, the plugin allows an ajax datasource http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html

Comment: I have used this $('#example').dataTable().fnClearTable(); but still  didin't succeded.